# FireEvent in IE 11/Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I have this situation of migration from IE 9 to 11 with added support for Firefox and one of my collegue has replaced

```
form.fireEvent("onsubmit");
```

with the following block

```
var event; // The custom event that will be created
if (document.createEvent) {
  event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  event.initEvent("submit", true, true);
  form.dispatchEvent(event);
} else {
  event = document.createEventObject();
  event.eventType = "submit";
  form.fireEvent("submit");
}

form.submit();
```

I couldn't understand what it means. Also is the above block correct?

Comment: `var event;` - bad start ... IE has a global variable called `event`

Answer (score 0):

1. > `if (document.createEvent){}`

   Checking if this supported, since many method use to create custom event is depreciated
2. > `event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");`

   if above is true then create `Event` object

   `HTMLEvents` is the type of event to be created. [Check Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent#Notes) for more
3. > `event.initEvent("submit", true, true);`

   Defining the event name.Here the event name is "submit".

   Normal syntax is  `event.initEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);`
4. > `form.dispatchEvent(event)`;

   `dispatchEvent` is the last step of the create-init-dispatch process,  which is used for dispatching events into the implementation's event model.[More about dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)
5. > `event = document.createEventObject();`

This is to handle Internet Explorer. It generates an event object.

6. > `event.eventType = "submit";`

   It will create an event of type `"submit"`
7. > `form.fireEvent("submit");`

   This will fire the event on `form`

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: So why this two sections? Which is for IE? Which is for other browsers?

Comment: else loop is checking ie . I have mentioned it

Comment: thanks. actually am not a front end developer. One more doubt how form.fireEvent("onsubmit"); has changed to form.fireEvent("submit"); Whats the difference

Comment: Seems it is just change of the event name . previously the event name was onsubmit and it is simply submit